# Django Admin DataError: Value too long for type character varying(150)

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I'm running into a really strange behavior in Django admin. I have this model definition:

```
class WebPublication(DatesInfo):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class WebArticle(MsnPublication):
    pass
```

And the following form and admin code:

```
class WebArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=150)

class WebPublicationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   def some_method(self, obj):
       return 'Hello!'

class WebArticleAdmin(WebPublicationAdmin):
    form = MsnArticleForm
    list_display = ('title', 'author', 'pub_date', 'preview_link')

admin.site.register(MsnArticle, MsnArticleAdmin)
```

This is pretty standard, which is why I say I find this strange and try to give as many details as possible.

As you can see, `WebPublication` has a `varchar` with a maximum length of 200, which can be confirmed in the table description (PostgreSQL by the way):

```
      Column       |           Type           |     Modifiers
-------------------+--------------------------+-------------------
 title             | character varying(200)   | not null
```

However, I get the following exception from Django admin when I try to edit the `title` field. I'm making it 150 chars, which is the maximum allowed by the input field according to the definition of `WebPublicationAdmin` (that's expected).

> ```
> DataError: value too long for type character varying(150)
> ```

Notice how the error message doesn't reflect the current state of the model. (I ran a migration and it was successful because PostgreSQL says so.)

What could possibly be wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you are overriding the title's max_length with 150 here;

```
class WebArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=150)
```

The admin is using this form to validate the data. Just change the 150 -> 200.

Comment: That didn't do it I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the error was coming from a different field.The error isn't descriptive and it doesn't tell which field is violating the length constraint. If anyone is having the same problem, try inspecting all field of the model.